# How to show rotating image if the some process is running in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show rotaing image when I click on tab. The tab content is some ui which takes some time to load. I want to show that rotating image for that period of time. Is there a way to do that?

Actually I have tabcontrol. When I clicked on tab, its content get loaded i.e. some operation like fetching the data and loading the ui. But this takes some time to load. I want to show the some image for that period of time. Here the I tried one rotating image but that image is not rotating when tab content is loading. After the tab content gets loaded, the image rotates properly.
I want to rotate that image when the tab content is loading only that period of time.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post. It sounds similar.

[Show animation till an operation completes wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554189/show-animation-till-an-operation-completes-wpf)

Here is some information on how to do a rotation:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx

Comment: But if the ui is loading then how can I display only the image